# How do I count divs clicked using an event listener in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying the count the total number of divs clicked and exactly which ones were clicked. I'm using an event listener because the onclick is already used. Let me clarify a bit more, first, here's my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">1</div>
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">2</div>
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">3</div>
</div>
<div id="dis"></div>
```

```
.selected {
    background: white;
}
```

```
var numClicked = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
numClicked.forEach(numClicked =>
numClicked.addEventListener('click', clickedDivs)
)

function clickedDivs () {
    i = 0;
    numClicked.forEach(numClicked => 
    i++
    var x = document.getElementById("dis");
    x.innerHTML = "Squares selected: " + i;
    
}
```

What I'm trying to do with my javascript is count how many divs are selected. I'm also trying to tell exactly where ones were clicked. Let's say 1 and 2 were clicked, how do I find those were clicked and total number of divs clicked using js?

Comment: didn't we solve this yesterday?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a way to do it with event listeners. I needed to do it with event listeners because I'm using onclick to toggle the background. Also, I have over 7000+ divs and I don't want to change somefunction(1), somefunction(2) .... somefunction(7000+). I didn't realize that when I asked the question previously so I asked a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong here is:

1. You are initialising i within the onClick event fn. which will always reset the value to 0 when ever the div will be clicked.
2. you are not storing anywhere which div is clicked
3. You are adding you'r listener on wrapper instead of .square (if you are not trying to get the value of clicked wrappers instead of clicked square)
   So you can modify you'r javascript like this

```html
<style>
   .square{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: grey;}
   .selected {
      background: white;
   }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">1</div>
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">2</div>
        <div class="square" onclick="classList.toggle('selected')">3</div>
</div>
<div id="dis"></div>

<script>
var numClicked = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
numClicked.forEach(numClick => {
  numClick.addEventListener('click', clickedDivs)
}
)

var itemsClicked = [] //to store which div is clicked
function clickedDivs (e) {
    var value = e.target.innerHTML;
    //edit
    if(itemsClicked.indexOf(value) != -1) itemsClicked.splice(itemsClicked.indexOf(value), 1)
    else
      itemsClicked.push(value);
    var x = document.getElementById("dis");
    x.innerHTML = "Squares selected: " + itemsClicked.join(",");
}
  
</script>
```

edit:
added to code to remove data from the list if already exist.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for. I'm wondering is there a way to remove a selected square from the list if it clicked again? For example, if square 1 was selected then selected again it gets removed from the selected squares.

Comment: Yes you can remove the selected square from the list. just do a check before inserting and if the element is already present in the list remove it or if not there in the list insert it. eg: ```if(itemsClicked.indexOf(value) != -1) itemsClicked.splice(itemsClicked.indexOf(value), 1) else ...do other stuff```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attach a handler to each div, you can use 1 window event listener. Give each clickable div an id that contains "clickable" so the event listener can filter out divs you aren't tracking. When you first click a tracked div, set its id as a key within a global object and assign 1 as the value; on additional clicks, increase value by 1.

```js
const clicks = {};

window.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
  const id = e.target.id;
  if(!id.includes("clickable"))return;
  clicks[id]? clicks[id] += 1 : clicks[id] = 1; 
  console.log(clicks);
},)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="clickable1" class="square">1</div>
        <div id="clickable2" class="square">2</div>
        <div id="clickable3" class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved by jQuery.

```js
var count;
  $(".square").click(function (){
      count = count+1;
      $("#dis").html(count);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class=square">1</div>
        <div class="square">2</div>
        <div class="square">3</div>
</div>
<div id="dis"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, I haven't tested it yet, test it and tell me how we adjusted it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="square" id="d-1">1</div>
     <div class="square" id="d-2">2</div>
     <div class="square" id="d-3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```
var count = [];

var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
wrappers.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('click',() => onClickwrapperSquare(square.id));


function onClickwrapperSquare(id) {
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  
  if(count.indexOf(id) == -1){
    count.push(id);
  }else{
    count = count.slice(count.indexOf(id)+ 1);
  }
  

  result.innerHTML = `Squares selected: ${count.length}`;   
}
```